# java/kotlin: format double/int with fixed total digits

Tags: java, kotlin, format, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I tried to search around but I'm having problem finding a complete solution for this problem:
I want to format an `Int` so that the total number of digits is always 3. A few examples:

```
1000000 -> 1,00m
678945 -> 678k
65432 -> 65,4k
5437 -> 5,43k
```

numbers should never be lower than 1000 or bigger than 1 billion so other cases don't really matter

this is the closest I've come to:

```
@JvmStatic
        fun formatPointsTop3(points: Int?): String {
            if (points == null) return ""

            val formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALIAN)
            val mathContext = MathContext(3, RoundingMode.DOWN)


            return when {
                points < 1000 -> {
                    "$points"
                }
                points < 1000000 -> {
                    val bigDecimal = BigDecimal(points / 1000.0, mathContext)
                    "${formatter.format(bigDecimal)}k"
                }
                else -> {
                    val bigDecimal = BigDecimal(points / 1000000.0, mathContext)
                    "${formatter.format(bigDecimal)}m"
                }
            }
        }
```

this works ok for most cases except for 1000000 which outputs 1m (I want 1,00m). Adding `formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2` adds decimals to all numbers.

Is there a way to achieve this without doing weird stuff directly on the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
fun formatPointsTop3(points: Int?): String {
            if (points == null) return ""
            if (points == 0) return "0"

            val maxNumberOfDigits = 3

            val multiplierExponent = log(points.toDouble(), 1000.0).toInt()

            val bigPoints = BigDecimal(points)
            val bigDivider = BigDecimal(1000).pow(multiplierExponent)
            val reducedPoints = bigPoints.divide(bigDivider)

            val intPart = reducedPoints.toBigInteger().toInt()
            val decimalPart = reducedPoints.subtract(BigDecimal(intPart)).toDouble()

            val numberOfDecimals = maxNumberOfDigits - (log10(intPart.toDouble()).toInt() + 1)

            var formattedString = "$intPart"

            if (numberOfDecimals > 0) {
                val multiplier = 10.0.pow(numberOfDecimals)
                val formatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance()
                formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = numberOfDecimals
                formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = numberOfDecimals
                val multiplied = (decimalPart * multiplier).toInt()
                formattedString += ",${formatter.format(multiplied)}"
            }

            formattedString += when (multiplierExponent) {
                0 -> ""
                1 -> "k"
                2 -> "m"
                3 -> "b"
                else -> ""  //this is not possible as max int is 2 billions
            }

            return formattedString
        }
```

it's quite ugly but it looks better than string manipulation imo

Answer (score 0):

There should be. First, figure out how you want to render it, which seems like you have a different take on exactly how per log(n) (as in, per how many digits are in the input). For 7 digits, you want to render the value, divided by a million, with 2 fraction digits. For 8 digits, you want value div million with 1 fraction, etc. It'll be a lot of code, maybe string manipulation is simpler.